# repeat special character with str_repeat

Tags: php, ascii, special-characters, repeat

i want to repeat special character 	 or TAB.

i try with str_repeat(str, int)

```
//my function repeat
function tab($num){
    return str_repeat('&#09;', $num);
}

//if I call
echo '<table>' . "\r\n";
echo tab(3) . '<tr>';

//the result
<table>
&#09;&#09;&#09<tr>;
```

I have tried several ways with single quote and double quote,
but the results is always wrong

Comment: What's the problem? Try to add `&nbsp;` after them.

Comment: Question is why you want to do such thing ?

Comment: @Rikesh to spruce up the indent in my code, to make it look more readable.

Comment: Use \t for printing tab

Comment: you are using browser or cli output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use \t for printing tab

```
function tab($num){
    return str_repeat('\t', $num);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function tab($num){
    return str_repeat(html_entity_decode('&#09;'), $num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to indent source code of your page, you should use `"\t"` instead of special characters.

```
function tab($num){
    return str_repeat('\t', $num);
}
```

Otherwise if you need to indent text on your page (which user would see), add `&nbsp;` after tabs.

```
<span>&#09;&#09;&#09;&nbsp;</span> some text
```

Anyway your should use MVC instead of such things.